# How to parse the input of below type in java using regexp?

Tags: java, regex

This is the input i'm getting from input file:

INPUT:

Input 1:

```
1 book at 11.49

1 music CD at 15.93

1 chocolate bar at 1.18
```

Input 2:

```
1 imported box of chocolates at 13.05

1 imported bottle of perfume at 41.20
```

There is one Product class which has the constructor like this:
Product(Name,Price,Quantity,isImported)

This is what i have tried, but this doesn't reads the multiple inputs and quantity of product:

```
    private static final String ITEM_DESCRIPTION_REGEX = "(\\d+)\\s((\\w+\\s)+)at\\s(\\d+.\\d+)";
    public static Product parser(String order) {
        Matcher m = parse(order);
        String name = m.group(2).trim();
        Product inputDataDTO = new Product();
        inputDataDTO.setGoodsName(name);
        inputDataDTO.setGoodsPrice(new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(m.group(4))));
        if (name.contains("imported"))
            inputDataDTO.setAdditionalImportedTaxPercentage(true);
        if (Util.getExemptedProductLists().contains(name))
            inputDataDTO.setExemptTax(true);
        return inputDataDTO;
    }
    public static Matcher parse(String description) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ITEM_DESCRIPTION_REGEX);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(description);
        matcher.find();
        return matcher;
    }
```

Comment: Please show up whatever you have tried.

Comment: added in the question, btw i'm not too good in regexp, i'm learning it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture all products, you need a `while` loop:

```
    private static final String ITEM_DESCRIPTION_REGEX = "(\\d+)\\s((\\w+\\s)+)at\\s(\\d+.\\d+)";
    public static List<Product> parser(String order) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ITEM_DESCRIPTION_REGEX);
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(order);
        List<Product> inputDataDTOs = new ArrayList<>();
        while(m.find()) {
          String name = m.group(2).trim();
          Product inputDataDTO = new Product();
          inputDataDTO.setGoodsName(name);
          inputDataDTO.setGoodsPrice(new BigDecimal(Double.valueOf(m.group(4))));
          if (name.contains("imported"))
            inputDataDTO.setAdditionalImportedTaxPercentage(true);
          if (Util.getExemptedProductLists().contains(name))
            inputDataDTO.setExemptTax(true);
          inputDataDTOs.add(inputDataDTO);
        }
        return inputDataDTOs;
    }
```